# Httpd not rewriting !hostname to hostname

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Simple:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443/80 --> https://login.example.com
```

One site, one hostname, one server.

So I've done this in the main httpd.conf to avoid virtualhost manips:

```
<Location />
    #redirects all traffic to ssl
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    #redirects all not hostname to hostname
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^login\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule /.* https://login.example.com/ [R]
</Location>
```

SSL redirect works perfect.

Hostname redirect I can't get to work for the life of me. Tried removing trailing '\', tried generic variable designations instead of static info like I have now. No dice.

Maybe I've been staring at it too long... Any insight would help tremendously.

EDIT: So it seems as though the IP is redirecting to the hostname, but not until after your prompted in the browser to accept the unsigned cert. Once you say ok it continues with the redirect. Any way around this?

Comment: Sorry but there is already dozens of questions on Pro Webmasters already regarding redirecting from non-ssl to ssl, and ip to domain and so on.

Comment: Your "problem" would seem to be with your cert. It is bound to the hostname, not the IP address. The cert is obviously checked before your other config kicks in. Maybe these related questions on SO will help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name